# Circumventing closure-borrowed variable lifetime limits

Tags: rust, lifetime, glium

I'm using the following code in order to run my `render::exec` function on each occurrence of a `RedrawRequested` event (issued by Glium):

```
event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
    match event {
        Event::RedrawRequested(_) => {
            let mut target = display.draw();
            render::exec(&mut target, &mut ctx, &font, &mut cache);
            target.finish().unwrap();
        }

        // ...

        _ => ()
    }
});
```

The issue is, I'm getting the following error on the `&font` reference:

```
borrowed data cannot be stored outside of its closure
```

`font` is indeed created before the call to `event_loop.run`, since it is a `rusttype::Font` struct that I need in order to render text inside my Glium app. I understand that since this is a `move` closure, the data from `font` will be free'd at the end of it, so the borrow checker doesn't allow `font` to be created outside of the closure, because it isn't ensured that the closure won't be called more than once (and indeed, it *is* called more than once).

I tried to circumvent this by removing the `move` keyword, but then the following error is triggered on each one of the variables that I borrow from inside the closure:

```
closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `ctx`, which is owned by the current function
may outlive borrowed value `ctx`
```

I understand that since the borrow checker cannot be ensured that these variables will last at least as long as the closure, it won't allow the latter to be referenced from inside the former.

Therefore, **I need a way to ensure the borrow checker that these variables *will* last at least as long as the closure**. One way to do that normally would be to pass them as parameters to the closure, but I actually cannot change the list of parameters that is passed, since I'm using `event_loop.run`, which has the following signature:

```
pub fn run<F>(self, event_handler: F) -> !
where F: 'static + FnMut(Event<'_, T>, &EventLoopWindowTarget<T>, &mut ControlFlow)
```

I went through the Glutin docs and couldn't find a way to store any data into the `EventLoop` (which is the type that dereferencing `EventLoopWindowTarget` gives), nor into the `ControlFlow` that is passed as a param.

Comment: Did you try keeping your font into a `Rc<rusttype::Font>`?

Comment: @rodrigo creating the Rc before the closure causes an error: "cannot move out of `font_ref`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure", because Rc does not implement Copy as far as I understand it

Comment: `Rc` is not `Copy`, but it is `Clone`. You clone it and move the cloned value into the closure.

Answer (score 1):

> font is indeed created before the call to event_loop.run, since it is a rusttype::Font struct that I need in order to render text inside my Glium app. I understand that since this is a move closure, the data from font will be free'd at the end of it, so the borrow checker doesn't allow font to be created outside of the closure, because it isn't ensured that the closure won't be called more than once (and indeed, it is called more than once).

That's not correct. It doesn't care that the `font` is created before the closure, because it's moved *into* the closure afterwards. Likewise calling the closure more than once, doesn't matter, the font now belongs to the closure.

A closure is a structure with an associated function, all the variables that are part of the environment are really set as members of the structure from which they can be pulled when calling the function in order to fill the free variables. That's about it. It has no specific issue with creating items outside the closure (how else would you close over them?), or with calling closures multiple times.

```rust
let font = Font;
let t: u8 = (0..5).map(move |_| Font::thing(&font)).sum();
```

What the error is saying is that inside the closure you're borrowing something and you're trying to move that borrow outside the closure.

Comment: How do I _not_ move it, then?

Comment: Why would you not move it? Moving it seems fine. It's the "escaping borrow" which is the issue and since you provide no information pertaining to that it's difficult to provide any help. Though an easy solution is to put the font behind an Rc, then you can have multiple owners, both outside and inside the closure.